# Screen scroll not starting from beginning - Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, scroll, scrollbar, singlechildscrollview

I am helping contribute a code and am stuck on a scrolling bug in flutter.
The screen when opened is started from the Google Maps widget
 [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1vpX.jpg)

But when I hold the screen and scroll above then the top content is displayed [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPq5r.jpg)

Now, I cannot interact with the top content since when I release the scroll hold it bounces back to start at the map.
I hope I made senseI cant attach a video here to describe it more accurately.
[Here is the link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u077qAmxPvpMWJGENZwOrdDDkXvLeJoi/view?usp=sharing) for the respective file associated with the screen,you can download it to check out the code:

The mobile app UI code starts from line 876.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your GitHub link is broken.

Comment: Sorry it must be private ig, i'll share the dart file

Comment: @Omkar76 I've edited the post, could you check now.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't executed your code because it depends on lot of your other files but from reading your code I think the problem is occurring because of [`extendBodyBehindAppBar`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/extendBodyBehindAppBar.html) of `Scaffold`. (Checkout line number 114 in given file). Removing this argument or setting it to `false` should solve the problem.

From the docs :

> If true, and an appBar is specified, then the height of the body is
> extended to include the height of the app bar and the top of the body
> is aligned with the top of the app bar.
>
> This is useful if the app bar's AppBar.backgroundColor is not
> completely opaque.
>
> This property is false by default. It must not be null.

Comment: Wow, thank you! I even knew this property but couldn't guess that was the sole reason for the bug. It works now, I thought it had something to do with scroll physics.